# Why the eigenstate of an even observable is an eigenstate of the parity operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, parity

Definition of an even observable: $B_+=\Pi B_+\Pi$, where $\Pi$ is the parity operator.

Consider an arbitrary even observable $B_+|\psi_b\rangle=b|\psi_b\rangle$, then
$|\psi_b\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\Pi$. (Cohen *Quantum Mechanics*, P.199)

How to show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $B_+=\Pi B_+\Pi$ multiply from the right by $\Pi$ and recall that $\Pi^2=\mathbb{1}$ so that
$$
B_+\Pi=\Pi B_+\, .
$$
In other words, $B_+$ and $\Pi$ commute.  Thus, they have a common set of eigenvectors and in particular the eigenstates $\vert\psi_b\rangle$ of $B_+$ with non-degenerate eigenvalues $b$ will also be eigenstates of $\Pi$.

To be more explicit, consider
\begin{align}
\Pi B_+\vert\psi_b\rangle&= b\Pi\vert\psi_b\rangle= B_+\Pi\vert\psi_b\rangle
\end{align}
showing that $\vert\phi_b\rangle:=\Pi\vert\psi_b\rangle$ is also an eigenstate of $B_+$ with eigenvalue $b$.  Hence, $\vert\phi_b\rangle=\Pi\vert\psi_b\rangle$ must be a multiple of $\vert\psi_b\rangle$.  Let $\epsilon$ be this multiple.  Then
$$
\vert\phi_b\rangle=\Pi\vert\psi_b\rangle=\epsilon \vert\psi_b\rangle
$$
so $\vert\psi_b\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\Pi$ with eigenvalue $\epsilon$.